# How to show numbers in these formats Android

Tags: android, variables, type-conversion

Example :
value  = 0.0

I want to covert it to

Ans  :value = 00.0

example

value = 12.0

Ans: 12.0

example

value = 1.0

Ans: 01.0

Right now for float values i am using String.format( " %.2f" ,variable_value)
is there any way like this to convert values

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.format method like below:

```
String value= "_%02d" + "_%s";
```

it converts numbers like :

```
String.format("%02d", 1); // => "01"
```

you can see [forrmatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) doc for other modifiers